# Is there a way to access the images one uploads to use in posts?

Tags: feature-request, images

I wonder if there is a way to have the images, one uploads to use in posts, available for later use.

I know that images we use for post are hosted by imgur, so I created an account (using Open ID as mathSE) in the site, but I can't find a way to associate the two accounts.

So far, what I can do is upload the image I need to imgur and then call it in the post I'm writing, but I wonder if there is an automatic way of do so.

Comment: Feel free in retag this

Comment: You put the pony tag on your own post? I must not understand this tag.

Comment: @mixedmath [explanation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5922206#5922206)

Comment: All in favour of deleting the idiotic [tag:pony] tag say aye.

Comment: What do you mean by "available for later use"? I.e. what exactly do you want to happen that doesn't already happens? As far as I'm aware there's nothing that prevents you from inlining an image in a post just because it has already been used in a different post.

Comment: @HenningMakholm say I use an image in a post. Later in the future, I'm doing something (not necessarily posting in SE) and then I recall "oh, I already have something like that in somewhere". What I wish is: login my imgur account, and look for by the desired image. Right now, what I have to do in order to recover the image is look for it in all the posts I have. In my case, that's not a very difficult task, but it will be useful if one have a lot of post in many sites. In summary what I want is all the images I have used in posts here, avalaible in my own imgur account.